# How to display fbx 3d model in android

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, fbx

How to display FBX 3D model in android.

I have fbx binary file which i have to load and display in opengl.

I dont want to use Untiy 3D framework for this. Please let me know how load Fbx 3D in android app.

Thank you

Comment: this may help you https://github.com/andresoviedo/android-3D-model-viewer

Comment: This doesn't support .fbx file format.

Comment: finally found lib three.js to render fbx 3D files (https://threejs.org/docs/)